# Unsubscribe button isn't disabled when I have already unsubscribed from "Tag watching" notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, tag-watching, email-notification

I have already unsubscribed from all the "Tag watching" notifications, but the button for "Unsubscribe from all" (notifications) is still enabled. I think it would be better if it is disabled if a user doesn't have any watched tags.

[image]

Comment: You're right. Moreover, that whole UI element shouldn't be there given tag notifications haven't been enabled on public sites. I'm adding it to our bug queue.

Comment: @BrianNickel it's relic from the past probably, when there were tag notifications to email, but SE nuked it when changing the tag popover design, for no reason.

Comment: Another point to note is that the button color does not match the site theme. It's **red** on *all* the sites. It [used to match the site theme before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzrHF.png), but now it doesn't, as you can see from the updated screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Eh, this specific UI was new at the time and unrelated to the SE filtered question system. I think the thought at the time was that we’d be rolling out the Teams tag notification system as a replacement for filtered questions, but that has yet to materialize. Regardless, I am now powerless to resolve this issue in any way and can’t say why I didn’t do more at the time.

Comment: @BrianNickel lol I know you can't do anything now, to be honest didn't notice it's old question until after submitting the comment. But I'm talking about ability to subscribe to tags in the old tag popover, not filtered questions. I'll look for old screenshot. [Found one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo8ie.png), clicking the "subscribe" let you choose how often you want to get emails for new questions with that tag, and it worked just fine. Until SE nuked it just because they changed design and couldn't fit in that link. One of the most silly things I've ever seen, but meh, what's done is done.

Answer (score 3):

Quite some time have passed since reporting this bug, but we fixed it now :) The button is now only available if there's something to unsubscribe from.
Hope that helps!