# No visual feedback when unsubscribing from all digests

Tags: bug, preferences, community-digests, email-settings-page

In the Community Digests page (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/current), if you try to unsubscribe from all digests, there is no visual feedback that anything happened. In fact the confirmation dialog is still open and it looks like nothing happened. However a network request is sent in the background and if you refresh the page you will see that you were in fact unsubscribed.

Here is a gif showing what it looks like:
[image: Gif showing the process of unsubscribing from community digests]

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the Community Digests page here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/current
2. Click on the button labeled "Subscribe to the Meta Stack Exchange community digest" if you are not already subscribed.
3. Click the "Unsubscribe from all" button.
4. Click the "Yes, unsubscribe from all" button in the confirmation dialog that appears.
5. Observe that nothing happens

#### Expected Behavior

There should be some kind of visual feedback that something happened. In this case, I think it's enough to at least reload the page.

Comment: This seems to be functioning similar to the "Yes, unsubscribe from all" button for Tag watching & ignoring: [Unsubscribe button isn't disabled when I have already unsubscribed from "Tag watching" notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325963/unsubscribe-button-isnt-disabled-when-i-have-already-unsubscribed-from-tag-wat)

Comment: @V2Blast any chance to throw this into the status-review queue? Or isn't it your decision? :-)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: I mean, I can – but I usually leave that to the mods unless it's an issue I intend to handle/triage myself.

Comment: That button isn't needed at all since there's already a toggle above to turn off community digests. (I intended to include this in my first comment, but ran out of time and eventually forgot..)